# How do I know if an M3U8 link is from a live transmission or a complete file?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, vps

### This is my problem

I have a downloader app, and one of it's features is downloading M3U8 links using FFmpeg under the hood

It only supports a selection of sites and platforms, but i don't want to add support for unknown origin links, not just because it's obviously missing the right headers, cookies and user agent and the user would have to put all of that to work, the main reason is that I don't know how to determine if that link leads to a complete file or if it leads to a live transmission

This is what happened:

A user of my app gave me a link to test it manually, i ran the code and I noteiced it was taking a lot of time to finish having a decent speed, the file was getting too big, and when i ask him where did the link came from he said it was from a Live TV stream: I had to cancel the download

So, how do i know in FFmpeg if a given M3U8 link  leads to a complete file rather than a live transmission?

Comment: A VoD playlist will have `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` at the end; a live playlist won't.

Comment: @Gyan Hopefully.  :-)

Comment: Never thought about that. Thanks @Gyan